# If statement not working (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement, floating-accuracy

This seems like really simple code but for some reason it just won't work. I need to output a value at certain times but the if statement doesn't seem to be evaluating. The following is the basic version of what I'm trying to do.

```
dt=.1

while t<=10:
     if t==5:
          print('yes')
     t+=.1
```

I've literally tried this in my code and I've even had it print t for every time step but it will not print 'yes.' I have other if statements in my code for an interval like

```
if 10<=t<60:
     do stuff
```

and these if statements run perfectly. I've tried `t==5.0` and `t==float(5)` just in case it needed that but it didn't work either. This is driving me crazy so if someone could please help me out that'd be great. I'm running this in Spyder on Ubuntu 12.4 and I've been getting a message saying `import sitecustomize` failed. Would this have anything to do with it? I've been running code for a while now with that message and it hasn't caused any problems before.

*Edit*

Got it to work, I used

```
if int(t)==5 and t<5+dt:
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: [Floating point inaccuracies](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Floating points do not have infinite accuracy - they take up a certain number of bits in memory (usually 64, or 32).

2) They use a binary internal representation for the mantissa (all the significant digits but the first, basically).

3) .1 can not be stored precisely as a binary representation - only as an infinitely repeating pattern of binary bits, and since the mantissa is only so large the floating point number is actually an approximation of .1, not really .1. (things like 0.5 and 0.25 can, however)

4) Therefore adding up .1s is not guaranteed to have perfect results - there will be errors from rounding the wrong way. For instance, .1 added to itself ten times might make 1.0000...1 or 0.999999...9.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic

Answer (score 2):

There are many comments why floating point arithmetics is inaccurate, but no answer how to fix the code.

To make a long story short, `while t<10.0+dt/2` and `if abs(t-5.0) <= dt/2`.

Answer (score 1):

a very poorly written example based on the code you wrote is working well enough for me.
So precision control is probably what you are looking for:
http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/decimal

```
    from decimal import *
    getcontext().prec = 3

    dt=.1

    t = 0

    while t <= 10:
        if Decimal(t) == 5:
            print('yes')
        t = Decimal(Decimal(t) + Decimal(dt))
        print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `t` is floating point and is represented with not 100% accuracy in machine code. You need to either convert it to integer, or change the `if` condition so that it fixes this issue (cast to integer or use inequality).

Answer (score 0):

Try this convert t (which is float) into integer and then compare..

```
if int(t) == 5:
   ...
```

OR

```
import math
t_flr = math.floor(t)
if t_flr == 5:
   ...
```

Comment: I would rather use `round` than `floor` since you do not know in which direction the errors will be.